# Uncaught (in promise): Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular4-forms

I am unable to solve this issue. The code is copied from Angular docs.

TS File:

```
export class FormsPage {
  todo: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.todo = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      description: [''],
    });
    this.todo.valueChanges.subscribe(data=>this.todoOnDataChange(data));
  }
  todoOnDataChange(data: any): void {
     console.log(data);
  }
  logForm(){
    console.log(this.todo.value)
  }
}
```

HTML File

```
<form [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Todo</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="title"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea formControlName="description"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!todo.valid">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

What's wrong with the code? I just need to develop a form and onSubmit it should call a specified question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added Formcontrol for variables. please check with the below code.

```
export class FormsPage {
      todo: FormGroup;
      title : FormControl;
      description : FormControl;
      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.title = new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]));
      this.description = new FormControl();
        this.todo = formBuilder.group({
          title: this.title,
          description: this.description
        });
        this.todo.valueChanges.subscribe(data=>this.todoOnDataChange(data));
      }
      todoOnDataChange(data: any): void {
         console.log(data);
      }
      logForm(){
        console.log(this.todo.value)
      }
    }
```

**Update - 1**
Above code is written on Module file instead of Component file. issue got resolved after moving the code.

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: share the full line of exception with file name and line number. Example EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./EditPatientComponent class EditPatientComponent - inline template:1:10 caused by: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance.

Comment: When I change it to `this.title = new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.required]));`  Same error, Screenshot: [link](http://prntscr.com/h6tbs6)

Comment: edited few lines by fixing syntax errors and added return type for title and description

Comment: this is removed from this.formBuilder. please try this also, there is some small bug in building that formbuilder object only. if it's not working I will run this in a sample project

Comment: Can you tell me what to replace in place of `formbuilder`. I am new to Ionic

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the FormGroup?

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: `import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RegisterPage } from './register';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: I can't see the FormGroup instantiation.

Can you please try `todo: new FormGroup()`

Comment: `Typescript Error '(' expected.`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is happening in your HTML. `[formGroup]="todo"` may be set before your form is initialized. Set it in an `ng-container` with an `*ngIf` to wait for the form to be initialized.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="todo">
    <form [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
    //...
    </form>
</ng-container>
```